# Issues with Devise confirmable emails and paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, paperclip

I need some change tracking for my devise User model. I am trying out paper_trail, but it's causing problems when changing emails and reverting. I can demonstrate the problem in a few lines from rails console below:

```
1.9.3p385 :048 > u = User.create email: 'aaa@bob.com', password: 'password', username: 'bob'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'aaa@bob.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'bob' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'aaa@bob.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'zNfBSVLJJ9nF4y5sanVU' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`confirmation_sent_at`, `confirmation_token`, `confirmed_at`, `created_at`, `current_sign_in_at`, `current_sign_in_ip`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `last_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_ip`, `remember_created_at`, `reset_password_sent_at`, `reset_password_token`, `roles_mask`, `sign_in_count`, `unconfirmed_email`, `updated_at`, `username`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:15:53', 'zNfBSVLJJ9nF4y5sanVU', NULL, '2013-03-05 13:15:53', NULL, NULL, 'aaa@bob.com', '$2a$10$1BrAH1yqgF3qbgkmpMPl/uE0UY792aB8fvYKLksMnyQsn7sM/dY4O', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, '2013-03-05 13:15:53', 'bob')
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:15:53', 'create', 9, 'User', NULL, NULL)
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 9, username: "bob", email: "aaa@bob.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$1BrAH1yqgF3qbgkmpMPl/uE0UY792aB8fvYKLksMnyQs...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 13:15:53", updated_at: "2013-03-05 13:15:53", roles_mask: nil, confirmation_token: "zNfBSVLJJ9nF4y5sanVU", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2013-03-05 13:15:53", unconfirmed_email: nil>
1.9.3p385 :049 > u.confirm!
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `confirmation_token` = NULL, `confirmed_at` = '2013-03-05 13:16:23', `updated_at` = '2013-03-05 13:16:23' WHERE `users`.`id` = 9
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:16:23', 'update', 9, 'User', '---\nusername: bob\nemail: aaa@bob.com\nencrypted_password: !binary |-\n JDJhJDEwJDFCckFIMXlxZ0YzcWJna21wTVBsL3VFMFVZNzkyYUI4ZnZZS0xr\n c01ueVFzbjdzTS9kWTRP\nreset_password_token: \nreset_password_sent_at: \nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \ncreated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.205031000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.205031000 Z\nroles_mask: \nconfirmation_token: zNfBSVLJJ9nF4y5sanVU\nconfirmed_at: \nconfirmation_sent_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.204780000 Z\nunconfirmed_email: \nid: 9\n', NULL)
   (25.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
1.9.3p385 :050 > u.versions.length
  Version Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `versions`.* FROM `versions` WHERE `versions`.`item_id` = 9 AND `versions`.`item_type` = 'User' ORDER BY created_at ASC, id ASC
 => 2
1.9.3p385 :051 > u.email = 'bbb@bob.com'
 => "bbb@bob.com"
1.9.3p385 :052 > u.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'bbb@bob.com' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` = BINARY 'bob' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'bbb@bob.com' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `unconfirmed_email` = 'bbb@bob.com', `updated_at` = '2013-03-05 13:17:07' WHERE `users`.`id` = 9
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:17:07', 'update', 9, 'User', '---\nusername: bob\nemail: aaa@bob.com\nencrypted_password: !binary |-\n JDJhJDEwJDFCckFIMXlxZ0YzcWJna21wTVBsL3VFMFVZNzkyYUI4ZnZZS0xr\n c01ueVFzbjdzTS9kWTRP\nreset_password_token: \nreset_password_sent_at: \nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \ncreated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.205031000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-03-05 13:16:23.677037000 Z\nroles_mask: \nconfirmation_token: \nconfirmed_at: 2013-03-05 13:16:23.674113000 Z\nconfirmation_sent_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.204780000 Z\nunconfirmed_email: \nid: 9\n', NULL)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'KJHQCtu74MqUSAdczu3Q' LIMIT 1
   (11.2ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `unconfirmed_email` = 'bbb@bob.com', `updated_at` = '2013-03-05 13:17:07', `confirmation_token` = 'KJHQCtu74MqUSAdczu3Q', `confirmation_sent_at` = '2013-03-05 13:17:07' WHERE `users`.`id` = 9
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:17:07', 'update', 9, 'User', '---\nusername: bob\nemail: aaa@bob.com\nencrypted_password: !binary |-\n JDJhJDEwJDFCckFIMXlxZ0YzcWJna21wTVBsL3VFMFVZNzkyYUI4ZnZZS0xr\n c01ueVFzbjdzTS9kWTRP\nreset_password_token: \nreset_password_sent_at: \nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \ncreated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.205031000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-03-05 13:16:23.677037000 Z\nroles_mask: \nconfirmation_token: \nconfirmed_at: 2013-03-05 13:16:23.674113000 Z\nconfirmation_sent_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.204780000 Z\nunconfirmed_email: \nid: 9\n', NULL)
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
 => true
1.9.3p385 :053 > u.email
 => "aaa@bob.com"
1.9.3p385 :054 > u.unconfirmed_email
 => "bbb@bob.com"
1.9.3p385 :055 > u.confirm!
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'bbb@bob.com' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` = BINARY 'bob' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'bbb@bob.com' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `confirmation_token` = NULL, `confirmed_at` = '2013-03-05 13:18:08', `email` = 'bbb@bob.com', `unconfirmed_email` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2013-03-05 13:18:08' WHERE `users`.`id` = 9
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:18:08', 'update', 9, 'User', '---\nusername: bob\nemail: aaa@bob.com\nencrypted_password: !binary |-\n JDJhJDEwJDFCckFIMXlxZ0YzcWJna21wTVBsL3VFMFVZNzkyYUI4ZnZZS0xr\n c01ueVFzbjdzTS9kWTRP\nreset_password_token: \nreset_password_sent_at: \nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \ncreated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.205031000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-03-05 13:17:07.788127000 Z\nroles_mask: \nconfirmation_token: KJHQCtu74MqUSAdczu3Q\nconfirmed_at: 2013-03-05 13:16:23.674113000 Z\nconfirmation_sent_at: 2013-03-05 13:17:07.790567000 Z\nunconfirmed_email: bbb@bob.com\nid: 9\n', NULL)
   (15.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
1.9.3p385 :056 > u.email
 => "bbb@bob.com"
1.9.3p385 :057 > u.versions.last.reify.save # revert to before the email confirm
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'aaa@bob.com' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` = BINARY 'bob' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'aaa@bob.com' AND `users`.`id` != 9) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `created_at` = '2013-03-05 13:15:53', `updated_at` = '2013-03-05 13:17:07', `confirmation_token` = 'KJHQCtu74MqUSAdczu3Q', `confirmed_at` = '2013-03-05 13:16:23', `confirmation_sent_at` = '2013-03-05 13:17:07', `unconfirmed_email` = 'aaa@bob.com' WHERE `users`.`id` = 9
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:20:13', 'update', 9, 'User', '---\nusername: bob\nemail: bbb@bob.com\nencrypted_password: !binary |-\n JDJhJDEwJDFCckFIMXlxZ0YzcWJna21wTVBsL3VFMFVZNzkyYUI4ZnZZS0xr\n c01ueVFzbjdzTS9kWTRP\nreset_password_token: \nreset_password_sent_at: \nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \ncreated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.000000000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-03-05 13:18:08.000000000 Z\nroles_mask: \nconfirmation_token: \nconfirmed_at: 2013-03-05 13:18:08.000000000 Z\nconfirmation_sent_at: 2013-03-05 13:17:07.000000000 Z\nunconfirmed_email: \nid: 9\n', NULL)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'q9Y5ovWigLySxvz7PsaB' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `created_at` = '2013-03-05 13:15:53', `updated_at` = '2013-03-05 13:17:07', `confirmed_at` = '2013-03-05 13:16:23', `confirmation_sent_at` = '2013-03-05 13:20:13', `unconfirmed_email` = 'aaa@bob.com', `confirmation_token` = 'q9Y5ovWigLySxvz7PsaB' WHERE `users`.`id` = 9
  SQL (17.4ms)  INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2013-03-05 13:20:13', 'update', 9, 'User', '---\nusername: bob\nemail: bbb@bob.com\nencrypted_password: !binary |-\n JDJhJDEwJDFCckFIMXlxZ0YzcWJna21wTVBsL3VFMFVZNzkyYUI4ZnZZS0xr\n c01ueVFzbjdzTS9kWTRP\nreset_password_token: \nreset_password_sent_at: \nremember_created_at: \nsign_in_count: 0\ncurrent_sign_in_at: \nlast_sign_in_at: \ncurrent_sign_in_ip: \nlast_sign_in_ip: \ncreated_at: 2013-03-05 13:15:53.000000000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-03-05 13:18:08.000000000 Z\nroles_mask: \nconfirmation_token: \nconfirmed_at: 2013-03-05 13:18:08.000000000 Z\nconfirmation_sent_at: 2013-03-05 13:17:07.000000000 Z\nunconfirmed_email: \nid: 9\n', NULL)
   (7.0ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Now, we have reverted the user to the state before the new email was confirmed:

```
1.9.3p385 :059 > u = User.where(username: 'bob').first
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'bob' LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 9, username: "bob", email: "bbb@bob.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$1BrAH1yqgF3qbgkmpMPl/uE0UY792aB8fvYKLksMnyQs...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 13:15:53", updated_at: "2013-03-05 13:17:07", roles_mask: nil, confirmation_token: "q9Y5ovWigLySxvz7PsaB", confirmed_at: "2013-03-05 13:16:23", confirmation_sent_at: "2013-03-05 13:20:13", unconfirmed_email: "aaa@bob.com">
1.9.3p385 :060 > u.email
 => "bbb@bob.com"
1.9.3p385 :061 > u.unconfirmed_email
 => "aaa@bob.com"
```

As we can see, this is not the state of the User before. I guess this is because Devise detects an email change and what was set as the new email is set as the unconfirmed email. Is there anyway I can bypass this ONLY when reverting to a previous version of this object?

Also, I notice Devise executes 2 `USER users` statements for a single email update (the 1st being a subset of the 2nd). Any reason for this and is there a fix? It adds an additional, unnecessary version record for the User.

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time mucking with both devise and paper_trail and believe I've figured out how to manually change emails and skip the (re)confirmable options.

```
# skipping the initial confirmation
user = User.new email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'secret', username: 'foo'
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
user.versions.length # => 1

# skip the reconfirmation
user.email = 'bar@baz.com'
user.skip_reconfirmation!
user.save
user.versions.length # => 2

# revert
reverted_user = user.versions.last.reify
reverted_user.live? # => false
reverted_user.skip_reconfirmation!
reverted_user.save
reverted_user.live? # => true
reverted_user.email # => "foo@bar.com"
```

The `skip_reconfirmation!` makes the save set the `email` field directly and not set it to `unconfirmed_email`.

Edit: after more work, I'm confused yet again about what paper_trail is doing:

```
let(:user) { User.new(username: 'bob', email: 'bob@default.com', password: 'secret101') }  
it "can revert to a previous version" do
  user.save # version 1 (unconfirmed)

  user.confirm! # version 2 (confirmed)

  user.email.should eq 'bob@default.com'
  user.unconfirmed_email.should be_nil

  user.update_attributes email: 'bob@builder.com' # version 3, 4 (un-reconfirmed)
  user.versions.should have(4).items

  user.email.should eq 'bob@default.com'
  user.unconfirmed_email.should eq 'bob@builder.com'

  user.confirm! # version 5 (reconfirmed)
  user.versions.should have(5).items

  user.email.should eq 'bob@builder.com'
  user.unconfirmed_email.should be_nil

  # revert to the first confirmed user
  reverted_user = user.versions[2].reify
  reverted_user.email.should eq 'bob@default.com'
  reverted_user.unconfirmed_email.should be_nil
  reverted_user.should be_confirmed
  reverted_user.should_not be_live
  reverted_user.skip_reconfirmation!
  reverted_user.save!.should be_true
  reverted_user.should be_live # FAILS

  live_user = User.where(username: 'bob').first
  live_user.should be_live
  live_user.should be_confirmed
  live_user.email.should eq 'bob@default.com'
  live_user.unconfirmed_email.should be_nil

  user.email.should eq 'bob@builder.com' # => passes
  user.should_not be_live # => FAILS
end
```

I don't understand why the 2 items annotated with "FAILS" are failing the spec